# AngularJS Change api request from php to JSON

Tags: php, angularjs, json, api

Hi I've got this app which can connect to an API.

Only problem is it can only `get` API requests from an `PHP` file.

I want to change the code so that it wil accept `.json` API files

**Factory**

```
factory.readProducts = function(){
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
    });
    console.log(factory.readProducts)

};
```

Currently my `GET` method should be presumably be changed to `fetch`

**Controller**

```
$scope.readProducts = function(){

    // use products factory
    productsFactory.readProducts().then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.todos = response.data.records;
         console.log($scope.products)
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        $scope.showToast("Unable to read record.");
    });

}
```

**JSON method**

```
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

according to [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) it's the basic way to acces an JSON API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change the controller from:

```
$scope.readProducts = function(){

    // use products factory
    productsFactory.readProducts().then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.todos = response.data.records;
         console.log($scope.products)
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        $scope.showToast("Unable to read record.");
    });

}
```

To :

```
$scope.readProducts = function(){

    // use products factory
    productsFactory.readProducts().then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.todos = response.data.records;
         console.log($scope.products)
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        $scope.showToast("Unable to read record.");
    });

}
```

The `$scope.todos = response.data.records` needed to be changed to `$scope.todos = response.data` because of the structure of the API. It had noting to do with the file being `JSON` or `PHP`